# How can I install NVIDIA in non-interactive by SaltStack

Tags: nvidia, salt-stack

I'm new with SaltStack.

I need to install NVIDIA on minion server running CentOS 7 with SaltStack only.

In the gpu/init.sls file:

```
install_nvidia:
  cmd.script:
    - source: salt://gpu/files/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-375.20.run
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - shell: /bin/bash
    - args: -a
```

I run:

```
sudo salt minion_name state.apply gpu
```

I get the error:

```
...
 stderr:
                  Error opening terminal: unknown.
...
...
Summary for minion_name
------------
Succeeded: 0 (changed=1)
Failed:    1
```

How can I get more verbose information about the reason it failed?
I believe it wait to user input but I don't know what

Also how can I install NVIDIA on CentOS 7 with non interactive way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get more verbose information about why a Salt state has failed by running it locally using salt-call -l debug.

```
salt-call -l debug state.apply gpu
```

In your case, you have to be aware that installing the NVIDIA driver on Linux will require you to run the installer without a graphical session present. The simplest way to do this will be to check if you're currently in a graphical session (with systemd) and then drop do multi-user.target if so:

```
enter-multiuser:
  cmd.run:
    - name: systemctl isolate multi-user.target
    - onlyif: systemctl status graphical.target
```

Then, you can install the NVIDIA driver silently using something like

```
gpu-prerequisites:
  pkg.installed:
    - pkgs:
      - kernel-devel

download-installer:
  file.managed:
    - name: /tmp/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-375.20.run
    - source: salt://gpu/files/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-375.20.run


install-driver:
  cmd.run:
    - name: /tmp/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-375.20.run -a -s -Z -X
    - require:
      - file: download-installer
      - pkg: gpu-prequisites

start-graphical:
  cmd.run: 
    - name: systemctl start graphical.target
    - unless:  systemctl status graphical.target
    - watch:
      - cmd: install-driver
```

Comment: `systemctl --quiet is-active graphical.target` may be preferable to use over `systemctl status graphical.target` since it just provides the exit code and no stdout.